# Disk actions are not available for some drive in Disk Management

Tags: windows, formatting, pata, disk-management

I have plugged old E-IDE PATA drive into my motherboard and it detected it, unfortunately, Windows only see this drive but can't do anything with it. Why?

[image]

Comment: May be too many primary partitions? What a third party tool says about that like Easeus Or MiniTool Partition wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Because, as you can see in your screenshot, it hasn't recognized the filesystem format of the volume.  See where the other volumes in the screenshot say "NTFS" and that one does not say anything at all.

To see more information, use a more informative tool.  For example: crank up `diskpart`, switch to the relevant disk and partition with `select disk` and `select partition`, and view the partition information with `detail partition`.